# Adding Image to a database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to add an image to a BLOB field in a mysql database. The image is going to be less then 100kb in size. However I am running into problems and was wondering what would be a better way to add this data to the database?

com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Data' at row 1

```
PreparedStatement addImage = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Images (Width, Height, Data) VALUES (?,?,?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Below is the method that I am using to add the image into the database.

```
public int addImage(Image image) throws SQLException, IllegalArgumentException
{
    this.addImage.clearParameters();
    byte[] imageData = ImageConverter.convertToBytes(image);
    int width = image.getWidth(null);
    int height = image.getHeight(null);
    if (width == -1 || height == -1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must load the image first.");
    }



    this.addImage.setInt(1, width);
    this.addImage.setInt(2, height);
    this.addImage.setBytes(3, imageData);
    this.addImage.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet rs = this.addImage.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();

    return rs.getInt(1);
}
```

[SQL Definition for the table](http://pastebin.com/m3cd428c2)

After Changing the datafield type to a Mediumblob and attempting to place a 140kb image file into the database i received a different error.

com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large

Is the problem the way in which i am trying to add the data to the database. Should I take a different approach? If so which way?

Comment: It may be worth posting the definition of the table you're trying to add the image to.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a `MEDIUMBLOB` instead of a `BLOB`.  `BLOB` is limited to 64KB whereas a `MEDIUMBLOB` column can hold 16MB.

See the 'Storage Requirements for String Types' section of [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Answer (score 2):

To deal with [PacketTooBigException](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/PacketTooBigException.html), it looks like you need to tweak a config variable, max_allowed_packet.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html .  However, by default MySQL 5.1 should give you no problems with up to 1MB .  What version of MySQL are you using (both server and client).

Answer (score 1):

Try setBlob instead of setBytes

Answer (score 0):

Just execute below query at the start of the project...

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*number of MB
```

i.e.

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*14
```

***Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320236/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception)***.